# Convert record to list

Tags: list, ocaml, record

Suppose

```
type pair_int = {l1:int; l2:int, ..., ln:int}
let test = {l1=2; l2=4, ..., ln=71}
```

I thought I could do something like `map (fun (x,y) -> y) test`, but it doesn't work

How can I get the list `[2,4, ..., 71]` from `test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no nice way to do this inside the OCaml type system. You can't map over the fields of a record because they can be of all different types. Your type `pair_int` looks suspiciously like a list or an array already. The field names don't add any semantic content, and the fields are all the same type. You might consider just using a list or an array instead.